# how to add +1 to code ' 001' and to the code ' 009 ' in MySql?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to add +1 to code '001' but I get '2' and not ' 002  and +1 to code '009' but I get '10' and not '010'.

Table:

```
create table example
(
    code        varchar(7),
    row1        varchar(10),
    row2        varchar(7),


CONSTRAINT pk_code PRIMARY KEY (code)

);
```

Insert:

```
insert into example(code, row1, row2) 
values('001','x1', 'y1');

insert into example(code, row1, row2) 
values('009','x2', 'y2');
```

I try the next query:

```
select code+1 from example;
```

MySql returns me:

```
+----------+
|    code  |
+----------+
|        2 |
|       10 |
+----------+
```

Comment: To make a math operation MySQL converts your string to a number and the result is of course a number too. Use `LPAD`

Comment: You can't do math on strings ('001' is not a number), so it has to be converted from a string to a number in order to add. If you want it to again be a zero-padded string representation of that number, convert it back and add the right number of zeros to the left side.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a math operation MySQL converts your string to a number and the result is of course a number too. Use `LPAD` to turn it into a string again

```
select LPAD(code+1, 3, '0') from example;
```